# Convert array of string to array of struct in spark java

Tags: java, arrays, apache-spark

I have a bunch of json data in the below format

```
{"name": "Michael", "age": "30", "producta1": "blah1", "producta3": "blah2"}
{"name": "Michael", "age": "30", "producta1": "blah3", "producta3": "blah4"}
{"name": "Michael", "age": "30", "producta1": "blah5", "producta3": "blah6"}
{"name": "Andy", "age": "28", "producta1": "blah5", "producta3": "blah6"}
{"name": "Andy", "age": "28", "producta1": "blah6", "producta3": "blah6"}
{"name": "Andy", "age": "28", "producta1": "blah7", "producta3": "blah6"}
{"name": "Justin", "age": "12", "producta1": "blah5", "producta3": "blah6"}
{"name": "Justin", "age": "12", "producta1": "blah5", "producta3": "blah6"}
```

My below code is in spark were i do some kind of aggregation as below

```
 Dataset<Row> df = sc.read().json("/Users/g.bhageshpur/Downloads/spark-master/examples/src/main/examples/src/main/resources/people.json");

 df.createOrReplaceTempView("people");

 Dataset<Row> sqlDf = sc.sql("SELECT * FROM people");
 Dataset<Row> groupby = sqlDf.groupBy(new Column("name"), new Column("age"))
            .agg(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list("producta1"),
                    org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list("producta3"))
                    .toDF("name","age","producta1","producta2");
```

The above code gives me an output similar to

```
+-------+---+--------------------+--------------------+
|   name|age|           producta1|           producta2|
+-------+---+--------------------+--------------------+
|   Andy| 28|[blah5, blah6, bl...|[blah6, blah6, bl...|
| Justin| 12|      [blah5, blah6]|      [blah6, blah6]|
|Michael| 30|[blah1, blah3, bl...|[blah2, blah4, bl...|
+-------+---+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I have a requirement where I need to convert the above array values in the producta1 column to array of json objects something similar to

```
[{"producta1": "blah5"},{"producta1": "blah6"},{"producta1": "blah7"}]
[{"producta1": "blah1"},{"producta1": "blah3"},{"producta1": "blah5"}]
```

I tried something similar to

```
groupby.withColumn("newcolumn", functions.to_json(struct("producta1")));
```

The above snippet does not give me the desired result. How do I achieve array of Json objects in spark java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below code.

```
df
.groupBy($"name",$"age")
.agg(
    collect_list(to_json(struct("producta1"))).as("producta1"), // use to_json & struct functions here.
    collect_list(to_json(struct($"producta3"))).as("producta3") // use to_json & struct functions here.
).show(false)
+-------+---+---------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|name   |age|producta1                                                            |producta3                                                            |
+-------+---+---------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Andy   |28 |[{"producta1":"blah5"}, {"producta1":"blah6"}, {"producta1":"blah7"}]|[{"producta3":"blah6"}, {"producta3":"blah6"}, {"producta3":"blah6"}]|
|Justin |12 |[{"producta1":"blah5"}, {"producta1":"blah5"}]                       |[{"producta3":"blah6"}, {"producta3":"blah6"}]                       |
|Michael|30 |[{"producta1":"blah1"}, {"producta1":"blah3"}, {"producta1":"blah5"}]|[{"producta3":"blah2"}, {"producta3":"blah4"}, {"producta3":"blah6"}]|
+-------+---+---------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```